# Facebook Comments via Javascript

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-javascript-sdk

Does anyone know if it's possible on a FB app to insert the comments via javascript so I can access the elements via jQuery instead of using the `<fb:comments>` which inserts an iFrame which means I can't touch any of the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided just to build my own comments system and not worry about trying to use the Facebook comment system.

Answer (score 0):

The pre-made Facebook plugin has some big limitations, and this is one of them.  You can write your own comments tool (I have in the past for a file storage app I wrote many years ago allowing people to leave comments about files other people uploaded).  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ for how to interact with the Graph API.